# When print button is clicked, it prints full page in pdf format including navigation bar and everything. How to print just the quotaition?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf

This is my code to print the qoutation. I have used javascript for it. Can u tell me what should i do to print just the quotation and not the full page? This code prints the full web page. I want it to be printed in pdf format

```
<?php 
session_start();


if(empty($_GET['id']))
    {
        header("location:products.php");
    }

    require_once("include/database.php");

    $_SESSION['p_id'] = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * from products WHERE p_id='".$_GET['id']."'";

    $res = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die("wrong query " .mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) != 1)
    {
        header("location:products.php");
    }

?>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Oswald|Electrolize' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <title>Siddhivinayak Motors Pvt. Ltd. | Home</title>

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sliders/flexslider/flexslider.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />



    <!-- HTML5 detect touch events -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>


<body class="menu-1 h-style-1 text-1">
<div class="wrap">

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Header - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->   
    <?php 
    include("include/header.php");
    ?>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - end Header - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->   


<aside id="sidebar" class="one-third column">

        <div class="widget-container widget_compare">

    <div class="widget-head">
        <h3 class="widget-title">Price Quotation</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="entry-loan">

    <form action="php/service.php" method="POST" name="service" id="service" >
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>"/>
    <table>

       <tr height="40px">
       <td><label for="Vehicle name">Vehicle</label></td>
       <td style="padding:0 0 0 12px; ">
       <label>  
        <?php  
        echo $row['p_name'];
        ?>
    </label>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="40px">
     <td><label for="Vehicle name">Model</label></td>
    <td style="padding:0 0 0 12px; "><label>
    <?php  
        echo $row['p_subname'];
    ?>
     </label>
    </td>
     </tr>

    <tr height="40px">
    <td><label for="Vehicle name">Ex-Showroom price</label></td>
    <td style="padding:0 0 0 12px; ">
    <label><?php echo $row['showroom_price'] ?></label>

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="padding:70px 0 0 120px; ">
    <i>As on. &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;<?php  
            echo date("d-m-Y");
                ?>
<br/>
    Tax and insurance extra.<br/>
   All prices are subject to change without prior notice.<br/>
    Please contact the dealership for exact prices and offers.<br/></i>
    </td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="padding:0 0 0 12px; ">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="padding:0 0 0 20px; ">

     <script language="JavaScript"> 
    if (window.print) {
        document.write('<form><input type=button name=print value="Print" onClick="window.print()" class="button orange"></form>');
                            }
    </script>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>                    

    </form>

    </div>


        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - end Container - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->          

    </div><!--/ .main-->


    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Footer - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - --> 
    <?php
          include("include/footer.php");
    ?>

    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - end Footer - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->     

</div><!--/ .wrap-->
<?php
    include("include/login.php");
?>
<?php mysql_close($connection); ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/selectivizr-and-extra-selectors.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="sliders/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.gmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-impromptu.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: header('Content-type:application/pdf');

Comment: where do i have to add this code on the page?

Comment: Use a print stylesheet that sets `display: none;` on the navigation etc.

Comment: it should be on the top after the <?php tag...but i'm not sure it will working

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries.

```
.extra {
    display: block;
}

@media print {
    .extra {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

By default the element is shown, but when the browser wants to print the page, it sees the print media query and applies it, hiding the element(s).

If you want to print in PDF format, that's a whole different story. You'll need to send special PDF headers in your PHP before any output it sent to the client:

```
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
```